# Is there a way to prevent my react app from lagging/slowing down

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Devs. I just completed a project using react and it works fine on pc resolution/screen size.
As I reduce the screen size the app begins to lag/slow down. When In mobile size it freezes and doesn't respond. However, on enlarging the screen size it unfreezes and works fine.

this is the link to the app.

https://prismatic-begonia-ab7262.netlify.app/

thanks

Comment: (a) It works fine on my machine at any window size. I can't see any performance degradation (except exactly when resizing the window). The site remains responsive all the time. (b) How would you expect us to help without seeing any code?

Comment: That's the issue, I don't know which component's code to send.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same issue, when I was using backdrop blur.
Removing it will solve the problem, in case you have that in your code.
Hope it fixes anyone else's issues.

Answer (score 0):

the issue is within your css, `overflow-y` needs to be removed

```
.container .main-footer {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I'm curious... how could `overflow-y` in CSS cause the app to freeze on resize and use of mobile app?

Comment: Alright, this is very unexpected but it works, as soon as I commented the overflow-y, it stops lagging on smaller screen and mobile. Thanks a lot, boss.

Comment: @node_modules I have no idea, but its the only fix i could come up with.

Answer (score 0):

Your Navbar.js component could use a bit of cleanup. You are adding several resize event listeners and this can degrade performance. Make sure to remove the event listener when the component unmounts.

```
useEffect(()=>{
  window.addEventListener('resize', changeSize)
  if (size >= 991) {
    setMenuIcon(false)
  } else if(size < 991){
      setMenuIcon(true)
  }
  // You'll want to add this to remove the event listener once the component unmounts
  return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', changeSize);
},[size])
```

You can see there are far too many resize event listeners here after changing the window width a few times --->

[image: evidence]

Comment: Thanks,  initially forgot to add that. It's working fine now.  Once again, thanks for you assistance